# send data from ArrayList<String> to String Array (Android)

Tags: android, string, arraylist, arrays

i am working on an app in which i am loading images from url so i have saved some image url in ArrayList and i want to send it to String Array so i can load images.

i am trying to send data from ArrayList to String Array but i am not receiving data in String Array.

i tried this:

```
package com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class Constants {

    public static ArrayList<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
        LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
        LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
    }

    public static final String[] IMAGES = LIST.toArray(new String[LIST.size()]);

    private Constants() {

    }

    public static class Config {
        public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
    }

    public static class Extra {

        public static final String IMAGES = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGES";
        public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
    }

}
```

Note: if u want to suggest me this: then don't.

```
public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[]{
        "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q",
        "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q",
        "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q",
    };
```

because my task is to send data from ArrayList to String Array

Comment: Are you converting an `ArrayList` into a `String[]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String[] IMAGES;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
    LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
    LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
    IMAGES = LIST.toArray(new String[LIST.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change list to array in `main` method like this

```
public static String[] IMAGES;

  public static void main(String args[]) {
        LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
        LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
        LIST.add("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q");
        IMAGES = LIST.toArray(new String[LIST.size()]);
    }
```

Comment: got these errors using your code:

`Description Resource Path Location Type
The final field Constants.IMAGES cannot be assigned Constants.java /Universal Image Loader/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader line 14 Java Problem
The blank final field IMAGES may not have been initialized Constants.java /Universal Image Loader/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader line 8 Java Problem
`

Comment: @androidoverflow remove `final` from `public static final String[] IMAGES;`,see updated answer.

Comment: removed final and end-up with unfortunately app stopped.
 because i am accessing IMAGES in another class see this: `public void onImageGridClick(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, IMAGES);
  startActivity(intent);
 }` this activity starts first. after click button app unfortunately stops, **remember i am using universal image loader**

Comment: @androidoverflow It seems that `IMAGES` in your code is null,So first call your `Constants class` main function.